# When is Enhanced Domain going to be available to enable?

Tags: custom-domain, mydomain, critical-update

In the [help document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_domains_enhanced.htm&type=5&release=230), it states

> When: This functionality is available on a rolling basis starting in the Spring ’21 release and **is available to all customers by March 31, 2021**.

We've now passed that date and we meet the [criteria](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_enhanced_considerations.htm&type=5) for Enhanced Domain to be available - we have a deployed My Domain routed through Salesforce Edge Network.

However, checking in `My Domain` still presents no option to actually enable this as mentioned in the doc. It doesn't appear in production or in any of our sandboxes.

> From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter My Domain, and then select My Domain. **Under My Domain Details, click Edit. Select Use enhanced domains and save your changes**. After your new My Domain is provisioned, deploy it from the My Domain Setup page.

Even more confusing, is that there's settings that seem to provide what enhanced domain will provide (stabilizing URLs), but it specifically mentions those settings have no effect once enhanced domain is enabled.

[image]

Is there any action a customer needs to take to actually enable Enhanced Domains or does anyone who has it activated have any information on when/how they activated it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Salesforce Support

> I checked with the internal team and got to know that timeline has been postponed and **Enhance domain is available on rolling basis and available to all customer by 30 April 2021 now.** Team is working on the same and customer facing docs are being updated and you would mostly see the update by a day or so there

The help document from the question is not active anymore, but the [Summer '21 release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_domains_enable_enhanced_ru.htm&type=5&release=232) **used to show** the following

> When: Enhanced domains are available in Salesforce orgs with a
> deployed My Domain routed through Salesforce Edge Network by June 30,
> 2021. This feature is available to all orgs on a rolling basis starting in the Summer '21 release.

And has the following outdated information

> Salesforce enforces this update in Summer '22.

---

In January 2022, the enforcement of this update was [scheduled](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000DyXPOSA3) for all orgs in *Winter '23*, starting in August 2022 for sandboxes and October 2022 for production orgs. If you meet the following criteria outlined in [Availability and Enforcement](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_enhanced_considerations.htm&type=5)

- Hyperforce org

or

- org with a deployed My Domain routed through Salesforce Edge Network

Then you should be able to enable Enhanced Domains before the enforcement.

---

As of August 2022, it's now [noted](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_domains_enhanced_ru.htm&type=5&release=238)

> This update was first made available in Summer ’21 and was scheduled to be enforced in Winter ’23, but **we postponed the enforcement date to Spring ’23 for production orgs. For sandboxes and non-production orgs, the enforcement date is still Winter ’23 unless you enable a new org-level setting that postpones the enforcement to Spring ’23**

With a new option to postpone the enforcement in non-production orgs

> To postpone the enforcement to Spring ’23 for sandboxes and non-production orgs, from Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter My Domain, and then select My Domain. Under My Domain Details, select Edit, then select Postpone the enforcement of enhanced domains until Spring ’23. Click Save.

There's also a [help document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000358662&type=1) specifically outlining timeline regarding this.

Comment: According to a recent email from Salesforce, enhanced domains will be enforced in sandboxes and other non-production orgs in Winter'23. It does not mention a specific date or version for the enforcement in production orgs.

Comment: According to the current release updates (2022-8-11), enforcement in production orgs is scheduled for Spring'23.

Comment: I am not able to see checkbox Postpone the enforcement of enhanced domains until Spring ’23 in my dev sandbox. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Is it under Routing header in My Domain Settings? What release is your dev sandbox? You can also disable the `Use enhanced domains by default in new and refreshed sanboxes` setting in production org which does the postponement for each new/refreshed sandbox related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to check this, it could be the reson:

```
Setup => My Domain => Policies => Prevent login from https://test.salesforce.com
```

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/189048)