# Select "Enable Enhanced Domain " is not available

Tags: critical-update

As per this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339508/when-is-enhanced-domain-going-to-be-available-to-enable), the option for selecting Enhanced Domain will be available from JUNE 2021. However, I'm not able to find this option in my Project orgs(Sandboxes / Production).

How can I get this option to enable Enhanced Domain?

Comment: Your org might not meet the requirements: see Note in https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_enhanced_enable.htm&type=5